# Do we need to change anything in usual webpage loader for loading an AMP (accelerate mobile page) webpage in Android?

Tags: java, php, android, html, amp-html

This is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Main extends Activity { 
    private WebView mWebview; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        mWebview = new WebView(this);
        mWebview.loadUrl("https://ampbyexample.com/");
        setContentView(mWebview); 
    } 
}
```

But, it doesn't load an AMP webpage as fast as it usually did. It's load like an usual webpage.

Is there need any change in this code.

Answer (score 1):

The most important things is to enable javascript - the AMP runtime requires javascript to work. However, there are a few more things you can do to improve loading AMP pages in a webview on Android:

```
...

WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();

// Important: enable javascript
webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webViewSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);


// enable 3P cookies (important when loading AMP pages via a cache)
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
          && !cookieManager.acceptCookie()) {
  cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
}

// enable local storage
webViewSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(
webViewSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 
  webViewSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + mActivity.getPackageName() + "/");
}

// set the referrer to your app
Map<String, String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<>();
extraHeaders.put("Referer", 
    Intent.URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME + "//" + context.getPackageName());

webView.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
```

Finally, you can load AMP pages via the AMP cache which performs additional optimizations when loading an AMP page (see [this article](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/using_the_google_amp_cache/) on how to construct the URLs).

Please note: the cache will load only valid AMPs.